# Change location for web app not available in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm currently use azure in trial mode. I created a web app that use "South Central US" location. As far as I could see when I created this, I could not select anything else than South Central US, I would like to change this to north Europe. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Recently, I meet the same question. After I investigated the azure app service documents, I found I can use "Clone APP" feature to conveniently deploy my web app to another region.

1. Choose "Change APP Service Plan", and add a new premium service plan (So that I can use "Clone APP" feature).
2. Choose "Clone APP", then I can clone my app to another region.
3. Change the service plan to original and delete the other service plan.

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply pick a new region for your web app: It resides within an app service plan within a given region.

To deploy into a different region, you'd need to create a new app service plan in that target region, then redeploy your app there. If you're taking advantage of built-in source code management (e.g. github), redeployment should be fairly straightforward.

Your question around which regions your subscription exposes is off-topic: That's something you'll need to open a billing support ticket and discuss directly with Azure support about.

Comment: It seem like i'm only able to change location if I select anything else than the free plan :(

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to change the location instead of cloning or redeploy your app. Here is the process to change app service plan for the existing and running Web app

- Step 1:
  Create new App service plan as your preferred location and pricing tier
- Step 2:
  Select change app service plan under your web app settings blade - app service section and choose your available app service plan just you created in step 1. now it updates your plan.
- Step 3:
  Delete the previous app service plan from your resource group, otherwise charges will apply for the previous associated app service plan.